# Launch application in background

Tags: iphone, ios, background, push-notification, uilocalnotification

Is that possible to run/launch application in background. I mean not making visible it to user?
For example by receiving local/push notification, even if user doesn't open(brings to foreground) an application, somehow open it in background, "hidden" for user?
Regards.

Comment: Unclear question. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer no, you can run programs in background on the iPhone like: audio players, navigation or voip clients.

Also if you app does not come to the forenground there is no way to receive any notifications(local or push).

Answer (score 1):

The only applications that are allowed to do this are Newsstand applications in iOS 5.